# Cannot edit todo item in todo list

Tags: reactjs, setstate, onsubmit

I wanna edit my todo item but when i click on the edit button, nothing happens. Is my function wrong somewhere? Please help me to fix it! Btw, this function seems a little bit long and hard to understand for me. Do you guys have any cleaner codes can you recommend me?  Thank you so much!

Sandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wind-s30er?file=/src/components/Todo.js

Comment: Your Todo.js component is empty.

Comment: oops. so sory. I just updated it, please check!

Answer (score 0):

Here React state wont update as it shallow compares the todos state and not its values.

```
 const newTodos =  todos.map((item) => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item))
setTodos(newTodos)
```

It might fixes the problem since we creates the new copy of it. so State bound  to update here.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: btw, this is the link as i just updated, https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wind-s30er?file=/src/components/Todo.js, you can check!